# Safari very sluggish and beachballs quite a bit

Tags: macos, safari

I have an older iMac with 16 GB of ram and I'm running High Sierra and Safari 12.1.2. Recently, when I'm running Safari, I get very sluggish performance. I get a spinning beachball which lasts for up to a minute and constant page reloads due to "a problem". This is most notable when I go to the ESPN website but happens on other websites too. This doesn't occur using Chrome.

I have tried:

Restarting my iMac

Restarting Safari

Clearing the Safari cache

Closing other open windows

Trying Chrome

Nothing worked for Safari

**Does anyone know what could cause this?**

There is a very similar question that has been asked but the method mentioned there doesn't work for me.

Comment: Does Safari work well on a freshly created user account?

Comment: i don't know. How do I create a new user account?

Comment: See https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/set-up-other-users-mtusr001/mac

Comment: Chromes backend is pretty much like safari. You won’t notice too much of a performance difference unless one browser has more plugins. Firefox is a good browser to compare performance. However also try a different computer to make sure it’s not your network/router settings. Is anything else sluggish on your system? Sometimes slow browser/internet is a symptom of something else system wide unrelated to internet speed ect.

Comment: Have you checked for installed extensions in Safari?  (`Preferences...` -> `Extensions`)

Comment: Thanks all, yes I checked my extensions and remembered I had several 3rd party extensions.  I deleted those and a few others and the problem disappeared!  Thanks again to you all!